# ActiveAdmin nested resources link to actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have table `Fees` on show page and few panels with nested resources

How i can add links to edit, update, destroy my nested resources?

```
  show do |fee|
    attributes_table do
      row(:code, &:code)
      row(:fee_group) { |fee| fee.fee_group['name'] if fee.fee_group }
      row(:ssr, &:ssr)
      row(:costs) { |fee| fee.costs.map { |cost| cost['currency'] }.join(', ') if fee.costs }
      row(:seat_group, &:seat_group)
      row(:rules, &:seat_group)
    end
    panel 'Cost' do
      fee.costs.each do |cost|
        div class: 'list-item' do
          attributes_table_for cost do
            row :currency
            row :price
            row :price
            row :tax
            row :default

Here i need add links 

              end
            end
          end
        end
```

Answer (score 1):

Had to solve the same problem, I used a member_action to solved it. Here's my solution:

```
member_action :remove_member, method: :post do
   user = User.find(params[:user_id])
   resource.users.delete(user)
   redirect_to resource_path, notice: I18n.t('admin.clubs.remove_member_success')
end
```

In show section:

```
panel do
  table_for club.users do
     column :rut
     column :last_name
     column do |user|
       link_to(I18n.t('admin.clubs.remove_member'),
         remove_member_admin_club_path(resource, user_id: user.id),
         method: :post,
         data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' })
       end
   end
end
```

Comment: Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation.  Code only answers are not considered "good" answers.  From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review).

Comment: This does not satisfy DRY, please consider doing some research before posting answer : )